# Clock.Now not available in domain level abp.io

Tags: abp

Moving from aspnet.boilerplate to abp.io I found out [Clock](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.4/Timing#iclock) is no more a static object. It is a service (IClock).

My question is: how can I use its features in the domain level using the DDD model? For example: I have a class describing events (inspired by this abp.io [article](https://community.abp.io/articles/creating-an-event-organizer-application-with-the-blazor-ui-wbe0sf2z)):

```cs
    public class Event : FullAuditedAggregateRoot<Guid> {

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public bool IsFree { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

        public DateTime BookingTime { get; set; }

        public ICollection<EventAttendee> Attendees { get; set; }

        public void AddAttendee(Guid attendeeId) {
            if (Clock.Now < BookingTime) {    <== here!
                throw new BusinessException(
                    "Error.EventClosed",
                    $"You cannot book this event before {BookingTime}.");
            }

            // ...

            var attendee = new EventAttendee { UserId = attendeeId };
            _attendees.Add(attendee);
        }

        public Event() {
            Attendees = new List<EventAttendee>();
        }
    }
```

Here I'd like to use Clock.Now (available as static object in aspnet.boilerplate), but not in abp.io where it is available only as service.

Answer (score 0):

I often need this too. I solve `IClock` by taking parameter as in the example below, so I can take full advantage of `IClock`.

```
 public void AddAttendee(Guid attendeeId, IClock clock)
 {
        if (clock.Now < BookingTime) {   
            throw new BusinessException(
                "Error.EventClosed",
                $"You cannot book this event before {BookingTime}.");
        }

        // ...

        var attendee = new EventAttendee { UserId = attendeeId };
        _attendees.Add(attendee);
 }
```

I then pass it as an argument where I call it.

---

I think probably Extensibility is the main reason why it is not static like in aspnetboilerplate.

This usage makes sense to me, I hope it will be useful for you.

---

References:

1. https://volosoft.com/blog/Prefer-Singleton-Pattern-over-Static-Class
2. https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Timing#datetime-normalization
3. https://github.com/abpframework/abp#application-modules

Comment: Thank you @berkansasmaz. However your solution requires I pass an additional strictly not useful param to the method. I wander if It is more correct to create an `EventsManager` class for this.